# One domain, two different Vue sites, served from Cloudfront / S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm facing an issue where I have two separate `Vue` projects that are being deployed (compiled) to two separate S3 buckets called `ContentSite` and `DashboardSite`. The contents of `ContentSite` is at the root of the bucket with an `index.html`. The `Dashboard` S3 bucket has all it's contents in a `dashboard` subdirectory. So Like `DashboardSite/dashboard/index.html`.

I also have a Cloudfront distribution that has the following behaviors:

`Default (*)` --- `ContenSite S3 Bucket`

`/dashboard/*` --- `DashboardSite S3 Bucket`

The issue is with my Vue projects when I try to navigate to the sites I am just getting `key not found`.

How can I configure my Cloudfront distribution to serve content from the `ContentSite S3 Bucket` when I'm browsing `/` and then anything from `dashboard/*` serve content from `DashboardSite S3 Bucket` and have my Vue routing still work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Lambda@Edge function to rewrite the URL. [mplementing Default Directory Indexes in Amazon S3-backed Amazon CloudFront Origins Using Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/) is a good starting point to reference. You may need to change it a bit to meet your needs, but the idea is the same. You just need to modify the request coming in so that it sends it to the correct file in the S3 bucket.

This is an example simple rewrite that sends most traffic to `index.html`. It works well for SPA apps. Things like css files, images, JavaScript files, etc., are passed through as is. You may need to adjust those as well, given that the relative paths may need to be adjusted.

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

  if (new RegExp(/^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/).test(request.uri)) {
    request.uri = '/index.html';
  }

  return request;
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I have tried Lambda@Edge but was unsuccessful. How would you go about writing it?

Comment: I added a simple example of a rewrite rule.

Comment: Hey Jason, would you put this on Origin Request or Origin Response?

Comment: This would go on origin request. You are changing what you request from the S3 bucket.